# How to store subset of columns from a csv file?

Tags: pyspark, sql, hive

I need to create a table in `hive` (or `Impala`) by reading from a `csv` file (named *file.csv*), the problem is that this `csv` file could have a different number of columns each time I read it. The only thing I am sure of is that it will always have three columns called **A**, **B**, and **C**.

For example, the first `csv` I get could be (*the first row is the header*):

```
 ------------------------
|  X | Y | A | Z | B | C |
 ------------------------
|  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

and the second:

```
 ------------
|  C | A | B | 
 -------------
|  1 | 2 | 3 |
```

And I need to store this in a table, maybe an external table. Something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE file (A STRING, B STRING, C STRING)
AS
SELECT A, B, C
USING HEADER
LOCATION 'input/loading/';
```

That obviously does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Will you do any transformations before writing into an external table? I am asking that because you have a pyspark tag in the question. You can do some transformations in pyspark to your dataframes and write them to external tables.

Comment: I don't need to do any transformation, just to exclude the other columns. I would prefer a solution without pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

Hive's RegexSerDe which is often used to process logs could be used in your use case. You could use the regex to extract the first 3 columns from a line

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE file (A STRING, B STRING, C STRING)
AS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
      ('input.regex'='^(\\w+)\\t(\\w+)\\t(\\w+)(.*)')
LOCATION 'input/loading/'
```

The regex included is using pattern groups (\w+) to extract the first 3 columns and the last group (.*) is anything else which may be in the line

See more details here [Community Article](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-Regular-Expressions-to-Extract-Fields-for-Hive-Tables/ta-p/247562) and [Official Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe)